# How to use eval function in python correctly?

Tags: python, eval

I'm new to coding, stuck with a normal issue but can't get it:

```py
a=list(input("enter some values"))
b=eval(input("enter some values"))
print (a)
print (b)
c=eval(4+3)
print(c)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/adadad.py", line 5, in <module>
    c=eval(4+3)
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

What's causing the error and how do I correct it?

[image: Error image]

Comment: it should be `eval("4+3")` like the error message says

Comment: It is a type error as eval  accepts the string or bytes! [eval](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)

Answer (score 0):

the expression given in the eval function should in form of a string.
Like this eval("4+3"). Also keep in mind that eval function takes only one arguments(here on string)

Answer (score 0):

`4+3` yields an `int` object ("integer"; a number). Then you're sending that into `eval()`, which does not accept `int`s; only strings (text), bytes (binary data), or code objects (functions or lambdas).

So that's what's causing your error.

To fix it, you could do two things: `c = eval("4+3")` or `c = 4+3`. You should choose the latter. Let me explain why:

`eval()` takes some text, parses it as code, and executes it. This can sometimes be useful for running "dynamic" code, that is code that for whatever reason couldn't be part of your original program (e.g. user input). It is generally discouraged, because it's not safe for uncontrolled inputs.

Just writing `c = 4+3` directly is simpler, safer, and faster.

You should also remove the `eval()` around your `input()` call at the top. In fact, try entering `print(a)` or `raise Exception()` when the second "enter some values" prompt appears, and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `3+4` is evaluated at compile-time (converting python code to byte codes) and replaced by `7`. Here's the byte code of this piece of code `eval(3+4)`:

```py
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (eval)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (7)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

So you're executing `eval(7)` which does not make sense. You can give the expression as a string to the eval to make it work.

```py
>>> eval("3+4")
7
```